# Import from the same package, using package name

Tags: go, package

I've added dependency to https://github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn in Golang project. I've tried to build application, however I am getting error from one of the classes from `golearn` - this one: https://github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/blob/master/base/dataframe_go.go : `undefined: base`. I've tried to find what is the `base` package refering to. There is no imported package `base` in this file so it looks like it is import from the same package but using the package name. I mean, dataframe_go.go is in the same package (`base`) where is the imported struct (`FixedDataGrid`). How to solve this import issue?

Comment: It's a bug in that project, contact the maintainer or open an issue on GitHub.

Comment: So you can't import file from the same package, using the package name? Thanks, it explain a lot.

Comment: Correct. You can't import the same package, and you can't reference the same package qualified with the namespace.

Comment: See https://github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/pull/257 which fixes the error introduced in https://github.com/sjwhitworth/golearn/commit/4aff2a91fb1e765966d7d25cffbf984c76375a67.